# Xamarin - Upload to AppStore failure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have been successfully uploading binaries to the AppStore / TestFlight the last week but this morning i get this error. It is weird since i see according to my code repo that the info.plist file haven't changed. The info.plist file does contain this entry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you include other frameworks in your app, they must also contain the 'arm64' required device capability, try to add following code to your `info.plist`.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>arm64</string>
</array>
```